# Dynamic memory with C

Tags: c, malloc

```
struct forcePin {
    char _name[512];
};

struct forcePin *_forcePin[500000];    
_forcePin[i] = (struct forcePin *) malloc (sizeof (struct forcePin));
```

May I know what is the line as shown below doing?

```
_forcePin[i] = (struct forcePin *) malloc (sizeof (struct forcePin));
```

I am not familiar with c,if you can tell me how to make this line to be in C++ format as well.Thanks

Comment: See [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Comment: @hmjd Does the code mean _forcepin[i] is a pointer to an object of type forcePin?

Comment: @Jaden: Yes, absolutely. `_forcepin` is an array of pointers to `forcePin`

Comment: Aren't there a trillion questions about that in SO?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Memory Heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308751/what-is-a-memory-heap)

Comment: @xgbi Since when do people use the search tool before posting?

Comment: Be careful with your use of leading underscores. In global scope it's actually reserved in the C and C++ specifications, and double underscore is reserved everywhere.

Comment: Flagged.. I feel old on SO, maybe it reached a tipping point where 90% of the questions are now duplicates..

Comment: @xgbi I know about the memory heap and Malloc in C but not so sure the code i posted is doing the thing I thought of so I asked here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic memory allocation is so important in C that you should really learn it properly.

What the line in question does is allocating memory from the heap, namely `sizeof(struct forcePin)` bytes. The `malloc` function returns a generic pointer to this allocated memory, and that pointer is assigned to the pointer `_forcePin[i]`.

One thing about that line, you should *not* type-cast the return value of the `malloc` function.

---

In C++ you use the `new` statement to allocate pointers:

```
_forcePin[i] = new forcePin;
```

However, in C++ using pointers and dynamic heap allocations is discouraged. I would instead recommend you to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of non-pointer structures:

```
struct forcePin {
    std::string name;
};

std::vector<forcePin> forcePin;
forcePin.push_back(forcePin{});
```

Answer (score 4):

It is calling the [standard library function `malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), to allocate `sizeof (struct forcePin)` bytes of dynamic ("heap") memory.

It is then [pointlessly casting the returned pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and storing it in the variable `_forcePin[i]`.

It's not the optimal way to write this code, in my opinion it should be:

```
_forcePin[i] = malloc(sizeof *_forcePin[i]);
```

Note that if the allocation is broken out of a loop (as the `i` implies), then that code looks like it's allocating 512 * 500,000 bytes, or around 244 MB of memory. Since it's done in half a million allocation calls, there will be considerable overhead, too.

If all the memory really is needed, it would be better to try for a single `malloc()` call and then split the allocated buffer into the 500,000 parts. Doing it that way would very likely be faster since `malloc()` can be expensive and half a million calls is a lot, but it would certainly save memory since there would be a *one* overhead cost rather than 500,000.

Comment: Don't you feel a little bit sad when people **still** cast the friggin' void pointer, 4 years after your excellent explanation as to why it's discouraged? :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Haha! :D Yes, it's saddening. It seems to be a powerful "anti-meme", no idea why it's so entrenched. I see it in textbooks, makes me want to shout. Luckily I can post links here, instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
_forcePin[i] = (struct forcePin *) malloc (sizeof (struct forcePin));
```

Allocates a memory block of size `forcePin`, and casts the allocated memory from (`void *`) to the `forcePin` type. In C++ you would do:

```
_forcePin[i] = new forcePin();
```

or better yet, you can have:

```
std::vector<forcePin> vec;
vec.push_back(forcePin());
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is your generic C-style memory allocation:

1. allocate memory (`malloc`) for exact number of bytes as is needed for structure `forcePin` (`sizeof(struct forcePin)`).
2. as the return value of `malloc` is a void pointer (`void *`) pointing to newly allocated memory, cast it to the pointer to `forcePin` structure (`(struct forcePin *)`)

C++ version would be something like:

```
_forcePin[i] = new forcePin;
```

- in C++, `struct` keyword is unnecessary when refering to struct type)
- don't forget to free the memory when not needed by `delete _forcePin[i]`

Because it looks like you just may want to create all 500000 `forcePin`s, you may do in in one step:

```
forcePin _forcePins = new forcePin[500000];
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you ask about allocate a block of memory (see `malloc()`), and stores its address into the `_forcePin` array, at index `i`.

In C++, you would have used `new`, ie: `_forcePin[i] = new forcePin`