# LeetCode: Address Sanitizer Violations

Tags: c

I am working through some of the examples but am continually getting these Address Sanitizer heap-buffer-overflow errors. I can't for the life of me figure out where the potential overflow is here:

```
bool detectCapitalUse(char * word){
    
    int CapitalLet = 0;
    int WordLen = sizeof(word)/sizeof(char);
    bool result = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < WordLen; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z' )
        {
            CapitalLet++;
        }
    }
    
    if( CapitalLet == WordLen )
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else if ((CapitalLet == 1) && (word[0] >= 'A' && word[0] <= 'Z'))
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else if (CapitalLet == 0 )
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }    
    
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: Here's the complete error message.

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000017 at pc 0x000000401850 bp 0x7ffcd5e90680 sp 0x7ffcd5e90670
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000017 thread T0
    #2 0x7f2bb38ea82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x602000000017 is located 0 bytes to the right of 7-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000017)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2bb4905f88 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bf88)
    #4 0x7f2bb38ea82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa[07]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

Comment: The problem (at least in part) is here: `int WordLen = sizeof(word)/sizeof(char);`.  The argument `word`  (`char * word`) decays into a pointer upon being passed as an argument, so `sizeof(word)` is really going to return `sizeof` a pointer, not `sizeof` the array that you likely passed.  And by the way, `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition.

Comment: Use `strlen` to get the length. `sizeof` is the size of a pointer, probably 8, not the length of the allocated memory it points to.

Comment: The shown code is unlikely to result in a heap overflow. Please clarify what the observed misbehaviour is. The only problem I could see (apart from not doing what it is supposed to do) is with words shorter than a pointer.

Comment: I am curious - would you please post the exact error for this exact code?  It does not appear to have the syntax to cause a heap overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Because nothing in your code uses [heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308751/what-is-a-memory-heap), there is nothing that would possibly cause *heap overflow*, but the problem that *can* be addressed is here:

```
int WordLen = sizeof(word)/sizeof(char);.
```

In the argument

```
(char * word)
```

`word`  decays into a pointer upon being passed as an argument, so

```
sizeof(word)
```

is really going to return sizeof a pointer (4 bytes for 32bit addressing), not sizeof the array that you likely passed. And by the way, `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition.

Change the expression to:

```
int WordLen = strlen(word);
```

Changing this single line allowed your code to work as I believe it was intended.  I tested it using the following calling method:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char word[] = {"this is A string"};
    bool res = detectCapitalUse(word);
    return 0;
}
```

***One caveat***:
If by chance you *did* use dynamically allocated memory in the calling function, or somewhere else that was not included in this post, *and* there was an attempt made to access that block of memory incorrectly, a *heap-buffer-overflow* could have been the result.

Comment: You are right. But do you think that this can cause what seems to be the misbehaviour observed by OP (i.e. a heap overflow)? I find the question either too unclear or to implausible to answer. Even if allowing for some creative interpretation of  "heap overflow":

Comment: @Yunnosch - I am editing, but yes I agree. At the very least there is some misunderstanding of the nature of the problem.

Comment: @ryyker - You were correct, that was the issue. Though it's curious that this caused what LeetCode deemed a "Heap oveflow". I posted the complete text of the runtime error message (before the change to strlen) in my original.

Comment: @nobby - Yes, I saw the error message.  Weird interpretation :)